# How to use double values in Protégé / OWL / DL for class expressions (Syntax)?

Tags: double, owl, semantic-web, protege, description-logic

I want to use double values for class expression syntax in Protégé but I can't find any examples. All are using integer values, not double. For instance: http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/class-expression-syntax/

For instance, I want to express the height of a person in meters:

- hasHeight value 1.89
- hasHeight min 1.70

How can I do this?

What currently works (according syntax): "hasHeight some xsd:double" infers that all instances that has a xsd:double value in the property hasHeight are instances. However, I want to restrict this to a particular value range. For example: between 1.80 and 1.70. How can I do this?

I thougt this is equivalent to queries from The DL Query tab where I can query relevant instances with "hasHeight some xsd:double[<=1.80]", but this is not allowed in the class expression editor in Protégé. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because Protégé is an editor for OWL 2, which in fact has some [restrictions on the datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Maps) allowed in facets:

> The OWL 2 datatype map provides the following datatypes for the
>   representation of real numbers, decimal numbers, and integers:
>
> ```
> owl:real
> owl:rational
> xsd:decimal
> xsd:integer
> xsd:nonNegativeInteger
> xsd:nonPositiveInteger
> xsd:positiveInteger
> xsd:negativeInteger
> xsd:long
> xsd:int
> xsd:short
> xsd:byte
> xsd:unsignedLong
> xsd:unsignedInt
> xsd:unsignedShort
> xsd:unsignedByte
> ```

Possible class expression:

`hasHeight some xsd:decimal[>= 1.7, <= 1.8]` (the parser in Protégé seems to need the spaces after `<=` symbol)

Comment: Thanks, changing it to xsd:decimal does not work. I can execute: "'hasHeight some xsd:decimal[>=1.7,<=1.8]" in DL QUery Tab, however, the same statement under in the class under "Equivalent To" does not work. How can I define ranges there? I can only state: "hasHeight value 1.71", but not a range. How can I do this?

Comment: The parser is a bit picky, use spaces after the `<,>,<=,>=` symbols: `hasHeight some xsd:decimal[>= 1.7, <= 1.8]`

Answer (score 2):

To define that individuals of type `Person` can have one or more `hasHeight` data properties you can state the following:

```
DataProperty: hasHeight
Class: Person
  SubClassOf:
    hasHeight some xsd:double
```

Note that this is different from cardinality restrictions, which limits how many times an individual of type `Person` can be associated via the `hasHeight` property. To specify that an individual of type `Person` has exactly 1 height you can specify it as follows:

```
DataProperty: hasHeight
Class: Person
  SubClassOf: 
    hasHeight exactly 1 xsd:double
```

Thus the complete definition is as follows:

```
DataProperty: hasHeight
Class: Person
  SubClassOf:
    hasHeight some xsd:double, 
    hasHeight exactly 1 xsd:double
```

Comment: Hm, ok. I just saw the current question.